# Is there a way to retrieve prefers-color-scheme (Dark / Light mode) programmatically in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, server-side

I would like to know if is possible to retrieve browser's settings of Dark/light mode programmatically ?

Currently I know that there's a way using @media (prefers-color-scheme) but I would like to know if is possible to detect that from server side?

Comment: Server side the only really useful information from the browser that is any where close to what you want is the agent string.

Comment: I tried to check the agent string if it says something about dark-light mode but unfortunately User-Agent doesn't seems to give that information. 

Here is what firefox shows 

[Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0]

Comment: Server side you will have little information about the user preference and configuration. Mostly it is about the browser, O/S, and with the only display information being the screen size: https://www.whoishostingthis.com/tools/user-agent/

Comment: I know but user-agent doesn't seems to give that information either.

Comment: It looks like `No` is the answer to your question: "is possible to detect that from server side?"

Comment: That's why I asked the question, because I have some "hope" to see if is possible to detect that from server side.